# make recursive tree and filter base user

Tags: c#, recursion, filter, tree, recursive-datastructures

data structure in C#

```
        public class KPIGroup
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int ParentId { get; set; }
        }
        public partial class KPI
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int? GroupID { get; set; }
        }
        public partial class User
        {
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public partial class User_KPI
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public int KPIID { get; set; }
        }
        public partial class User_KPIGroup
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public int? GroupId { get; set; }
        }
```

Assumptions to create a tree :

- root of tree ParentId is null.
- There may be multiple roots.
- Except for the root node, the other nodes have their parent field value which shows their parent value.
- KPIGroup has self relationship, ParentId is associated with Id.
- Each KPIGroup can have many KPIs (one-to-many relationship).
- User and KPI have relationship intermediate class, User_KPI.
- User and KPIGroup have relationship intermediate class, User_KPIGroup.
- in the User_KPIGroup class, Specifies that each user UserID has access to the KPIGroup.
- in the User_KPI class, Specifies that each user UserID has access to the KPI.
- just leaf nodes have KPIs.
- In the resulting trees, there must be leaf-to-root paths.

Problem :

make data structure recursive tree from KpiGroup,
Then Create a data structure recursive tree KpiGroup, so that each user can access only her own KPIGroups and KPIs. These accesses are defined for each UserID in User_KPI and User_KPIGroup classes.

make data structure recursive tree from KpiGroup,
Then Create a data structure recursive tree KpiGroup, so that each user can access only her own KPIGroups and KPIs. These accesses are defined for each UserID in User_KPI and User_KPIGroup classes.